# No idea of sql to mdx

Tags: mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I have no idea how to do it in mdx as I have only worked in sql but how do I translate this query from sql to mdx?

```
select monthname, sum(sales) sales
from table
where dt between 20190315 and 20220204
group by monthname;
```

Thank you for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of assuming that SQL and MDX can be translated back and forth. The nature of multi-dimensional databases means that the basic concepts which apply to the two query languages are very different.

Sometimes you can get similar answers, of course. In your case, the following MDX would give the sort of thing you were after...

```
SELECT 
{[All Time].[2019].[March]:[All Time].[2022].[February]} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[Sales] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cubename]
```

... although this would look at 20190301 to 20220228 which is not exactly what your SQL query did.

Comment: Thank you Magnus.
Indeed, almost but not what I require. I will keep trying and looking for the solution.
Greetings.